# PHP получение писем из Outlook

Tags: php, битрикс, email, imap

Всем привет! Народ, столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:

Есть на работе почтовый ящик. Из него нужно каким то образом получать письма с вложениями.

Сделал на php вот такую вот страницу:

```
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Title");

if (!$USER->IsAuthorized()) {
    $APPLICATION->AuthForm('');
}

?>



<?
    class Email_reader {

        // imap server connection
        public $conn;

        // inbox storage and inbox message count
        private $inbox;
        private $msg_cnt;

        // email login credentials
        private $server = '<сервер>';
        private $user   = '<логин>';
        private $pass   = '<пароль>';
        private $port   = 143; // adjust according to server settings



        private $hostname = '{<сервер>:143/imap/ssl}INBOX';
        //private $hostname = '{<сервер>:143/imap/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
        private $username = '<логин>';
        private $password = '<пароль>';

        // connect to the server and get the inbox emails
        function __construct() {
            $this->connect();
            //$this->inbox();
        }

        // close the server connection
        function close() {
            $this->inbox = array();
            $this->msg_cnt = 0;

            imap_close($this->conn);
        }

        // open the server connection
        // the imap_open function parameters will need to be changed for the particular server
        // these are laid out to connect to a Dreamhost IMAP server
        function connect() {
            //$this->conn = imap_open('{'.$this->server.':'.$this->port.'/notls}', $this->user, $this->pass);
            $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to mail.nsd.ru: ' .imap_last_error());

        }

        // move the message to a new folder
        function move($msg_index, $folder='INBOX.Processed') {
            // move on server
            imap_mail_move($this->conn, $msg_index, $folder);
            imap_expunge($this->conn);

            // re-read the inbox
            $this->inbox();
        }

        // get a specific message (1 = first email, 2 = second email, etc.)
        function get($msg_index=NULL) {
            if (count($this->inbox) <= 0) {
                return array();
            }
            elseif ( ! is_null($msg_index) && isset($this->inbox[$msg_index])) {
                return $this->inbox[$msg_index];
            }

            return $this->inbox[0];
        }

        // read the inbox
        function inbox() {
            $this->msg_cnt = imap_num_msg($this->conn);

            $in = array();
            for($i = 1; $i <= $this->msg_cnt; $i++) {
                $in[] = array(
                    'index'     => $i,
                    'header'    => imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $i),
                    'body'      => imap_body($this->conn, $i),
                    'structure' => imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i)
                );
            }

            $this->inbox = $in;
        }

    }


    $reader = new Email_reader();

    //phpinfo();
?>

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Открываю страницу в браузере, получаю вот такую ошибку:

```
Cannot connect to <имя_сервера>: Can't open mailbox : no such mailbox
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Как это лечится.
В php.ini расширение php_imap.dll раскомментировано. Веб-сервер Apache перезапускал.
Помогите кто может пожалуйста.
CMS: 1C-Bitrix

Comment: в настройках почтового сервера imap smtp активированы и настроены верно?

Comment: Где лежат эти настройки почтового сервера imap? А то я без понятия

Comment: Всё зависит от программы, которая выполняет эти функции, в некоторых настройки можно редактировать только через интерфейс программы.

Comment: А где эти настройки могут лежать? Хотя бы в теории?

Comment: Не имею представления, я всегда использовал интерфейс программы.

Comment: Поправил код, теперь получаю сообщения, но вот вложения, а именно PDF-файлы сохранить себе не могу.
Не получается сюда php-код вставить, т.к. он длинный, и этот сайт его не пропускает.

Comment: Вложения в письмах оформлены как строки, не помню точно но что типа <file1>D4im...l8d</file> следовательно нужно получить полный текст письма, и извлечь нужный тег.